# Old solutions being recalled in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have an odd scenario that I can't figure out, and would appreciate any advice offered.

I'm running VisualStudio 2010 pro.

I have a web application solution with 6 projects.

On one occasion I opened up some files from a number of backup solutions to look at some historic code. I viewed them and closed the files. I did this with my current project open.

I may have rebuilt the solution with them open but I'm not sure.

I recently did a 'find', searching the whole solution, and noticed that the files from the backups are referenced as being part of the solution.

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The solution was to publish the website rather than build it.